# TableView cell background color not changed when long pressed cell

Tags: ios, swift, cell

I have changed table view cell selection background color as below.

```
var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        let selectionColor = UIView() as UIView
        selectionColor.layer.borderWidth = 1
        selectionColor.layer.borderColor = utility.uicolorFromHex(0xEBEBEB).CGColor
        selectionColor.backgroundColor = utility.uicolorFromHex(0xEBEBEB)
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor
```

it change the background color but when i long press cell then background color remain same as default (dark grey). i want to change press and long press cell selection background color. how to do that ?

Comment: u can add long press gesture in on cell and its action set cell bg color.

Comment: When did you execute these code?

Comment: thanks llesh....it works using long press gesture..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable the selection style (because selection style contains default gray color)

```
cell.selectionStyle = .None
```

After that add long press gesture and on the action of it. do desired coding.

```
let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressGestureRecognized:")

tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
```

Now, add the `longPressGestureRecognized` function with the follow code:
Copy

```
func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

Inside the `longPressGestureRecognized()` function, start by getting the location of the gesture in the table view and the corresponding `tableViewCell`.

Add the following code inside the `longPressGestureRecognized()` function:
Copy

```
let longPress = gestureRecognizer as UILongPressGestureRecognizer

let state = longPress.state

var locationInView = longPress.locationInView(tableView)

var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)
```

Hope it helps.